# Associate std_logic_vector constant with input port VHDL-200X

Tags: vhdl, spi

I am trying to configure a chip over SPI interface using FPGA Spartan 6 Eval board. I just need to configure, I do not need to read the data from the chip, it will be done by another interface. Therefore, I want to send constants to register values of the chip. 
Errors I got are:

Line 59: Cannot update 'in' object data_config

Line 40: Unit  ignored due to previous errors.

I guess because I have my constant associated with input port. I did not know I am not allowed to do that. Is there a better way to approach this? Thank you.

```
  --------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Company: Quest
  -- Engineer: 
  -- 
  -- Create Date:    11:11:15 1/11/2018 
  -- Design Name: 
  -- Module Name:    main - Behavioral 
  -- Project Name: 
  -- Target Devices: 
  -- Tool versions: 
  -- Description: 
  --
  -- Dependencies: 
  --
  -- Revision: 
  -- Revision 0.01 - File Created
  -- Additional Comments: 
  --
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
     use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

  entity init is
    port(

          user_clk : in  std_logic; -- 27 MHz external clk input to FPGA
          data_config : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        config_reg : std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0);
          -- SPI 4 wires
          spi_miso : in  std_logic; -- Master in, slave out, just put high impedance since we don't read anything here, read out from LVDS
          spi_mosi : out std_logic; -- Master out, slave in, send config register values to TDC
          spi_ssn  : out std_logic; -- Slave select not, positive pulse to start, when LOW -> ready to shift of data in/out to/from device
          spi_clk  : out std_logic
      );

  end init;

  architecture Behavioral of init is


      -- Shift register
    signal shift_reg    : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
     signal count     : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0000";
  begin

          --* Config register settings *--
    config_reg_settings : process (config_reg)
      type config_reg is array (0 to 3)
        of std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
      constant data : config_reg := 
                              ("00110000",
                               "10000000",
                               "00110001",
                               "00000001"); 
    begin
      for i in data' range loop
        data_config <= data(i);
      end loop;
     end process;
  ---------------------------------------------------
     spi_clk <= user_clk;
  ---------------------------------------------------     
      -- * Master out slave in * --
     spi_process : process (user_clk)
     begin
      spi_ssn <= '1';
      if rising_edge (user_clk) then 
  --      count <= "0000";
        shift_reg <= data_config;
        spi_ssn <= '0';
        if count < "0100" then
          count <= count + "0001";
          shift_reg <= shift_reg (6 downto 0) & spi_miso; 
        end if;
      end if;
    end process;

    spi_mosi <= shift_reg(7); -- send out 8 bits at a time

  end Behavioral;
```

Comment: There are multiple flaws in your code: You should not use non-IEEE packages like `std_logic_unsigned`; use `numeric_std` instead. This code snippet is not complete; e.g. `serialize_byte` is not defined. Process `config_reg_settings` has no sensitivity list nor a wait statement. Shared variables are not properly supported by the Xilinx Synthesis Tool (XST). Moreover, the variable `count` is only used by one process. No need to declare it as `shared`. Use a local variable in the process; better use a signal. Process `spi_mosi_mux` doesn't implement a multiplexer as indicated by the label.

Comment: And make sure the error message and the code agree. Line 66 is blank which doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you @Paebbels for pointing out my horrible code. First time doing VHDL for me. I have fixed according to your suggestions as below.

Comment: I have edited my code so error messages match with lines. @Paebbels I also got rid of std_logic_unsigned and used only numeric_std; however, I got an error for "+" operator

Line 74: found '0' definitions of operator "+", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "+"

Comment: @BrianDrummond any suggestion for me on how to assign constant values to input port?

Comment: Whether `data` is constant or not isn't the issue. You cannot assign to an `in` port; that is the issue. An `in` port is an external source of data into the unit; if you assign to it you destroy that incoming data. If you want `data` connected to `data_config` you can either: (a) make `data_config` a signal (internal to the unit, not a port) or (b) move `data` outside, e.g. to the testbench that instantiates this unit for testing.

Comment: And line 74 : don't add std_logic_vectors. Use the right types for the job. If these are signed numbers, make them `numeric_std.signed`; if they are unsigned, `numeric_std_unsigned`.

Answer (score 3):

`config_reg` is of `bit_vector` type in your code. Change it to `std_logic vector`. Also you cannot drive input ports of an entity in code like that. You can write another top level VHDL file as a wrapper around this and then map those inputs to constant values using internal signals. Or convert those input ports into internal signals.